# Adding API response data to previous AsyncStorage data in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am working on a React Native app where i am adding API response data to AsyncStorage. I am sending multiple API requests and need to add every response to previously stored AsynStorage data. I have tried `AsyncStorage.mergeItem('key',JSON.stringify(data))` . But this is adding all data to one object only. I want every object seperately to be added.

Here's my sample API response:

```js
{data: [{type: "noun",
definition: "a domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, non-retractile claws, and a barking, howling, or whining voice.",
example: "she went for long walks with her dog"
}]
}
```

Now, i am saving this to AsyncStorage like this:

```js
var data = response.data
await AsyncStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Finally if i have a different response i want to add that to previous data like this:

```js
 [ {type: "noun",
    definition: "a domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, non-retractile claws, and a barking, howling, or whining voice.",
    example: "she went for long walks with her dog"
    },
  {type: "noun",
    definition: "a domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, non-retractile claws, and a barking, howling, or whining voice.",
    example: "she went for long walks with her dog"
    }
 ]
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
var data = response.data
AsyncStorage.getItem('favourites')
.then((favourites) => {
      const prevData = JSON.parse(favourites);
      const newData = favourites ? [...prevData,...data] : [];
      AsyncStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(newData));
});
```